# How to upgrade JUST the kernel?

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, kernel

I am trying to upgrade my kernel, but I would like to avoid updating all of the packages that a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` causes.  I am running Ubuntu 14.04, if that matters.  Is there a way to only upgrade the kernel?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can upgrade just the kernel by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

If you need headers for building kernel modules as well, you can also install them like so:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

It will update both `linux-image-generic` & `linux-headers-generic`.

Comment: `linux-generic` will install headers as well. And it is a typo anyway. The headers package is `linux-headers-generic`.

Comment: Isn't this not the correct command for Hardware enablement stacks as well as if you need say 14.04.5 won't this install the regular 14.04 kernel?